# How to add text in an textbox loaded in webview control in uwp?

Tags: webview, uwp

I have a webView and it can load an website say "google.com" and I also have a textbox with text entered "hello" in my application. What I want to do is when I press a button the text inside the textbox in my application should be copied to textbox in webView.
How do i do this ?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228874/7331395) answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`InvokeScriptAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301841.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method for [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView). Use JS code by invoking the eval function and providing your function code as a parameter.

This sample code is for bing.com

```
private async void Button_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var inputValue = TextBox.Text;
    var functionString = string.Format(@"document.getElementsByClassName('b_searchbox')[0].innerText = '{0}';", inputValue);
    await WebViewName.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
}
```